# Display surfnorm and save the values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using the surfnorm matlab function to calculate the surface normal. When I use it as: `surfnorm(pcloud(:,:,1),pcloud(:,:,2),pcloud(:,:,3));` the figure of the surface normal appears but the normal values are not saved. So I used :`[Nx,Ny,Nz]=surfnorm(pcloud(:,:,1),pcloud(:,:,2),pcloud(:,:,3));` but not its saving the normal values in [Nx,Ny,Nz] but not displaying the normal figure. So how to make both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the two actions you want to perform simultaneously appear to be mutually exclusive:

> ```
>  [Nx,Ny,Nz] = SURFNORM(X,Y,Z) returns the components of the 3-D 
>  surface normal for the surface with components (X,Y,Z).  The 
>  normal is normalized to length 1.
>
>  [Nx,Ny,Nz] = SURFNORM(Z) returns the surface normal components
>  for the surface Z.
>
>  Without lefthand arguments, SURFNORM(X,Y,Z) or SURFNORM(Z) 
>  plots the surface with the normals emanating from it.
>
>  SURFNORM(AX,...) plots into AX instead of GCA.
> ```

However, once created you can retrieve the normal vector data from the surface normal figure, as follows:

```
h=figure;
surfnorm(pcloud(:,:,1),pcloud(:,:,2),pcloud(:,:,3));
axesObjs = get(h, 'Children');
dataObjs = get(axesObjs, 'Children'); 
[Nx,Ny,Nz] = deal(get(dataObjs(1), 'XData').', get(dataObjs(1), 'YData').', get(dataObjs(1), 'ZData').');
```

It seems convoluted but if it's computational expense you are seeking to avoid this is probably the best way to do this.

**Edit:**

(1) You can substitute `h=figure` with a call to `figure` followed by `h=gcf`.

(2) My interpretation of the `Nx, Ny, Nz` vectors is that contain coordinates for the position and direction (not necessarily normalized) of the vectors drawn by `surfnorm`, as well as additional `NaN` values, so if you print out `[Nx,Ny,Nz]` you should see something like:

```
         0         0   -1.0000   <-- position of origin
         0         0   -1.0000   <-- direction of vector
       NaN       NaN       NaN   <-- nonsense
   -0.5878         0   -0.8090
   -0.7036   -0.0344   -0.9684
       NaN       NaN       NaN
   -0.9511         0   -0.3090
   -1.1341   -0.0543   -0.3685
       NaN       NaN       NaN
   -0.9511         0    0.3090
   -1.1341   -0.0543    0.3685
       NaN       NaN       NaN
    ....
```

Comment: its giving this error "Error using ==> get Invalid handle"  in this line " axesObjs = get(h, 'Children');"

Comment: @user1460166 : my guess is that it is a matlab version issue, which version are you using? The storage of data in the surfnorm object probably changed between versions. It's only a question of figuring out how: please post the result of `h` and `get(h)`

Comment: I'm using Matlab 2010a, h is 640x480 martix which is ok. get(h) is giving the same error.

Comment: @user1460166 : What an oversight! I missed placing `h=figure`, please see my changes. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I'm asking if this code is in a loop, in each iteration a new figure is made, I want to write on the same figure, how to do this? Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I just have a question, the images I'm working on has size 640x480, I noticed that each of Nx, Ny and Nz are of size 921600 which is 640x480x3 I don't know why? I'm thinking that they should only be 640x480 right?